# Is $\bigl(\sum {{x^n}\over{n!}} \bigr) \bigl(\sum {{y^n}\over{n!}} \bigr) = \bigl(\sum {{(x+y)^n}\over{n!}}\bigr)$ generalizable for series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Before I had to do a proof demonstrating the properties of exponential multiplication using power series expansions: $$ e^xe^y=e^{x+y}, $$ and the easiest and quickest way I could think of doing this would be: $$\left(\sum {{x^n}\over{n!}}\right)\left(\sum {{y^n}\over{n!}}\right) $$   and $$\left(\sum {{(x+y)^n}\over{n!}}\right)$$ for the left side.

Technically I know the two sides are I derived the power series from are equal, and it makes some sense consider the binomial expansion.

I wanted to know what this property is called and if it is more generalizable?

Comment: This is a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R} ,+) \to (\mathbb{R}^+$ , .). A generalization would be a structure preserving map between two groups (in other words group homomorphism)

Comment: Which property is "this"?

Comment: Thank you @RobertIsrael, I mean  a map $f:(\mathbb{R} ,+) \to (\mathbb{R}^+$ , .), such that $f(x+y)=f(x).f(y)$ and $f(0)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product of two series is called "Cauchy product"(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). By cauchy product we have

$$\left(\sum {{x^n}\over{n!}}\right)\left(\sum {{y^n}\over{n!}}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{x^k}\over{k!}}{y^{n-k}\over{(n-k)!}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}\cdot$$

Answer (score 0):

It *is* generalizable.

One form is
Abels' binomial theorem
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_binomial_theorem):

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}
(w+m-k)^{m-k-1} (z+k)^k 
=\dfrac{(z+w+m)^m}{w}.
$$

Another form,
provable by induction
(or from
$e^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^m x_i}
=\prod\limits_{i=1}^m e^{x_i}
$),
is

$$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^m \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x_i^k}{k!} 
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^m x_i \right)^k}{k!} 
.
$$